# Gas estimate infinite

Tags: solidity, remix, ropsten, ethereumjs

This is my code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract FirstContract
{
    address creator;
    uint256 priceOfATransaction = msg.value;
    uint256 totalAmount;
    address buyer;

    function FirstContract() public
    {
        creator = msg.sender;
    }

    function perSaleDetails() public
    {
        totalAmount += priceOfATransaction;
        //=========Detail of an order==========//
        priceOfATransaction = 0;
    }

    function sellerMoneey() public returns(bool)
    {
        if(msg.sender == creator){
            if(!creator.send(totalAmount)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

REMIX WARNING:-

> Gas requirement of function FirstContract.sellerMoneey() high: infinite. If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)

What do I need to modify

Comment: This may a bug in remix. It can not estimate gas for even simple function.

Answer (score 1):

Any use of `send()` and `transfer()` usually throws that compiler warning on REMIX even if there isn't loops or storage changes.

I assume you are just getting started with solidity and smart contracts, so there are a few things you will learn moving forward. Especially with lines like `uint256 priceOfATransaction = msg.value;`.

Your code is safe to compile.

Comment: Thanks. But my contract is deployed. What I am trying to figure out is everytime I send some ether to the contract it doesn't complete the transaction and fails.
Can you suggest a code that accepts the ether and then sends it to another address. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AgnishChakraborty Well, that's a totally different question...but none of your functions are `payable`. Without that, your contract is reverted. You need a `payable` method in order to receive anything int he contract.

Comment: @AgnishChakraborty secondly, this makes the line I mentioned even more of an issue since the `priceOfATransaction` is set to `msg.value` only once when the contract is created.

Comment: @AgnishChakraborty I'd help you with the code, but honestly, I have no clue what you're trying to accomplish with the state of the code initially. If you explain each function a bit more, I can help.

Comment: I want a contract that can accept ether. Has two functions that can calculate some variables passed. And a function to send the balance to the creator.